# Creating an efficient hash function for finding equal neighbors in 2D array

Tags: math, multidimensional-array

I am using a hash function for a game I am working on that looks up identical neighbors in a grid and returns a hash value. Once I have this value I want to place the appropriate game object in the scene, facing the correct direction which I would infer from the hash value.

The hash value works as such. I take the tile I am currently working on, and look at its eight neighbors, if they are the same tile, I add there value to the hash. There value is set based on there position in relation to the current tile I am looking up. Example:

[image]

The top left tile will always add 1, top middle always 2 etc.
If the center tile was a wall, and tiles 2 and 8 were a wall, the hash would return 10. It is relatively trivial. The issue I want to overcome is, the hash can potentially return 255 values. I only have 4 unique objects, the hash tells me which of the 4 to place and what direction to rotate it. In the example of 2+8 = 10, I wouldn't rotate it at all, but if the hash was 8+64 = 72, I would place the tile and rotate it 270 degrees.

There are obvious patterns, i.e 2 + 8, 2 + 16, 16 + 64, 8 + 64 are all the same identical object, just with a different rotation. Similarly, 1+2+8+16, 2+4+8+16 etc are the same object.

I have been trying to recognize the pattern on my own, but I am not making much progress. Is there a way to simplify the 255 potential outputs? I only have 4 objects, each object has a 4 potential rotations, so I know that each output on the graph has three other identical outputs in a different rotation. Was hoping to solve this problem on my own, but I am not having much luck. Thanks in advance for any help or input anyone may be able to provide. Going to continue working on this in the meantime.

Comment: If you only have 4 objects and possible 4 rotations, then you have at most 16 possibilities. You don't need all 255 hash values.

Comment: Your hash function is actually a [turnover necklace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) You can rotate necklace (and mirror it) to search for minimal value (of all possible rotations) which is a hash you need

Comment: This helps a lot. Thanks! Was able to get it working like I wanted. I should have noted that the 4 objects with 4 rotations was just the wall tiles which is my starting point, but the hash will control more placement as I develop. Thanks for the point in the right direction.